# Calculating free disk space

Tags: c++, windows, diskspace

What is the best method for calculating free disk space using C++ only.  My target platform is WinCE but most of the file operations are the same as normal Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean usage as in how much space is left? then try [GetDiskFreeSpace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364935(VS.85).aspx)
Or do you mean, number of reads/writes/current files open, speed etc?

Comment: There is also GetDiskFreeSpaceEx() which is simpler to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

OpenStore + GetStoreInfo.  STOREINFO gets you the used size, BytesPerSector * (NumSectors - FreeSectors).